# VBA to match across 2 tabs and multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

Folks,

I have what should be a simple one, but I'm have few concerns about the performance.

I have a spreadsheet that gets data from a crystal report and uses that to derive some supplier information. If the date received is incorrectly entered into the source system we can unfairly "black mark" the supplier, so we update the data in the spreadsheet, but obviously this gets overwritten daily.

I have some code that archives off any updates, but after a refresh I'd like to put that back.

So, where Tab1.A$1 = Tab2.A$1 AND Tab1.A$2 = Tab2.A$2 AND Tab1.A$3 = Tab2.A$3 AND Tab1.A$4 = Tab2.A$4 AND Tab1.A$5 = Tab2.A$5
then I need to update Tab1.A$6 = Tab2.A$6

I could probably fathom this out, (I'm a DBA rather than a programmer), but the way I'd do it would involve looping through the Tab1 and then for each line loop through Tab2,  swapping of tabs etc and is probably a very poor way of doing it. Is there a better way?

Cheers
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Just to understand this question correctly, can you please let me know if I am getting it right.
As I understand you are foucusing on updating the 6th(rows that are different) row of a sheet to match the other sheet's 6th row if all other fields matches. Am I correctly understanding this ?

If So why don't you copy all the data from one sheet to another ?

From another point of view, if the tab to be updated consists of a subset of objets (say supliers), then it cannot be done in a static manner....

Can you please explain little more may be with an example ?

Comment: If all the other fields Match then yes, update the 6th row, but this wont be all the records, I only want to update where the original date has been updated. For example I have 9000 records of dates received and want to update maybe 30 of them. Next month, the data will refresh and the 30 updates will have been lost, but I want to copy the updates back over.

Comment: for example, Supplier1, PONumber1 10/5/2014 gets updated to 9/5/2014 and is stored in a new tab as an archive. After the refresh I will want to update Supplier1, PONumber1 back to be 9/5/2014, but there will be lots that wont have updated.